# Swap HTML or Adding an ID (Swap HTML & Content Using Recommended Javascript Methods not Working)

Tags: jquery, html, linux, dom

Clue why the following isn't working?

**Note the very important-est point**: *there is **no** "ID" to target* with "getElementByID"--the end result desired is to actually add an ID to an "a" element, in fact:

The section of HTML I want to modify:

```
<div id="TicketPseudoReply" class="pseudo_reply">

                <a href="" id="FwdButton" rel="note-button" data-note-type="reply" data-domhelper-name="reply-button" data-replyto-handle="">Reply</a> / 
                  <a href="" id="FwdButton" rel="note-button" data-note-type="fwd" data-domhelper-name="fwd-button">Forward</a> /
                **<a href="#" rel="note-button" data-note-type="note" data-domhelper-name="note-button">Add note</a>**
            </div>
```

**Seeking either of the following:**

Replace a string with a new string,

```
<a href="#" rel="note-button" data-note-type="note" data-domhelper-name="note-button">Add note</a>
```

With

```
<a **ID="clickEnabledNoteButton"** href="#" rel="note-button" data-note-type="note" data-domhelper-name="note-button">Add note</a>
```

OR

```
<div id="TicketPseudoReply" class="pseudo_reply">

                <a href="" id="FwdButton" rel="note-button" data-note-type="reply" data-domhelper-name="reply-button" data-replyto-handle="">Reply</a> / 
                  <a href="" id="FwdButton" rel="note-button" data-note-type="fwd" data-domhelper-name="fwd-button">Forward</a> /
                <a **ID="clickEnabledNoteButton"** href="#" rel="note-button" data-note-type="note" data-domhelper-name="note-button">Add note</a>
            </div>
```

I've tried a few different methods--including those I could find here on Stack.

This is the latest I think should work but doesn't show the changes I'm looking for in the document[6]:

```
function findThirdDescendant(parent, tagname) {
  parent = document.getElementByID(parent);
  var descendants = parent.getElementsByTagName(tagname);
      if ( descendants.length )
      return descendants[2];
  return null;
}

var elementClick = findThirdDescendant("TicketPseudoReply", "a");

elementClick.setAttribute("id", "clickEnabledNoteButton");
```

But the underlying HTML I want to attack remains the same: still no "ID=clickEnabledNoteButton". x*D

[I've tried and read a lot](https://cmpstuff.blogspot.com/2016/05/swap-html-or-adding-id-swap-html.html) but really need to get this next step done.

Your superior wisdom (even if very mean) is very much appreciated and shall be paid forward.

References (mostly stack) Cited:

```
http://cmpstuff.blogspot.com/2016/05/references-cited-on-stack-question-yet.html

Enumerated "[1]", "[2]", "[3]" though the post on Stack* was significantly shortened. Refs offsite since anyone <10 rep = no >2 links. 
I realize, for good reasons.[7](also in the post linked)
```

Comment: This is way too long. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. (**minimal**)

Comment: _Thanks for pointing-out mcve._ :) **The important bit personally:** _the attempt in point (6) above. I can't figure-out why that doesn't work._ o.O @theblindprophet

Comment: else: issue's one that keeps appearing here on stack* so I documented attempts to use the various approaches suggested on the site in hopes of honing-in on what the issue might be. I was going for http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (Complete) and http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask (Constructive Subjective).